# How to visualize my first post with octopress?

Tags: octopress

I installed octopress (git,RVM) as documented on octopress.org
I created one post and executed the commands:

```
rake generate  
rake preview
```

This last command is never finished !?
Any explanation ?

- Ruby version 2.0.0

The command

```
rake watch
```

also loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rake preview` is a command which launches your site running locally on port 4000. Therefore if you execute that command and browse to localhost:4000 you should see your site. The command will appear to be running constantly (until you ctrl-c out) as it is running a server.

This is covered under the blogging basics - http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/

`rake watch` will also run continually as all it is designed to do is monitor for changes in your source and sass then if any are detected will automatically run a generate task.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see my site on localhost:4000 . I thought it was because I stopped the loops

Comment: @Bertaud - Yes you have to leave the `rake preview` command running to be able to view localhost:4000 - if you have it running and you can't see the site can you post the terminal output of the `rake preview` command for us?

Comment: Forget my comment. I stopped the loop and looked at localhost. I must not stop the loop and look at in the same time. I didn't undestand your explanation, now yes. Many thanks !